# How to disable 'Unterminated string literal' error highlighting in VSCode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I'm currently using a script language that is very similar to JavaScript, but it allows string breaks without any special line end markers. I.e. I can simply write

```js
var a = "one line
  second line
  third line
";
```

instead of adding a slash to the end of the lines, as it is required in JavaScript:

```js
var a = "one line \
  second line \
  third line \
";
```

So when I write a multi-line string without the slashes in the end, VSCode gives an error "Unterminated string literal.ts(1002)".

This language doesn't support JS template literals, so I can't use backticks for
multi-line strings either.

I know about `"javascript.validate.enable": false`, but it disables error checking completely, so it's not what I need in my case. I need error highlighting, but not for this error type.

Is there any way to disable error highlighting only for "Unterminated string literal.ts(1002)" error in VSCode?

Comment: out of curiosity, what language is this?